# Match columns with index in command line

Tags: match, text-files, tabular

There are two files which I have. The first contains data in one column and x rows and the other file contains the data as well in one column and y rows. Every row has a new line. The files look like:

```
0 
1
5
8
6
8
2
4
```

other file

```
1
6
2
4
```

I would like to generate a file in which I get the position of the other file entries in the first file such as in

```
2
5
9
10
```

is there an efficient way to do this in bash/perl/python?

Comment: That's not a good question for SO since you didn't show any effort to solve your own problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ while read i ; do sed -n '/'$i'/{=;q}' filea ; done <fileb
```

gives

```
2
5
7
8
```

Comment: does file A have to be the largr file?